# Why does useEffect expect dependencies which could cause endless loops?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm unsure weather this is a eslinter issue or a code issue but I'd like to clean up my code to have 0 warnings in the terminal. As it stands the only one I do not understand is the useEffect warning:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'readingsStore'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
```

The code that causes this is:

```
const preFlight = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(preFlight.current){
      preFlight.current = false;
      readingsStore.getDeviceIds();
    }
  }, [])
```

I understand that it wants the readingsStore to be mentioned in the dependency array, but this useEffect is my initial data fetcher when the component mounts. Giving it the readingsStore as a dependency doesn't make sense to me, could someone explain what I'm missing?

Note, this is an issue I have even when the dependency array isn't empty [], so removing it wouldn't be an option everywhere. Example, it expects the readingsStore here as well:

```
useEffect(() => {
    selectedDevice && readingsStore.setHistoricFilter({deviceKey: selectedDevice} as HistoricFilter)
  }, [selectedDevice])
```

Comment: If you are sure that you do not need any update when `readingsStore` might change, then it is fine

Comment: Yes, but that's the thing, the second useEffect directly changes a value that the warning for the dependency array expects. Which would cause and endless loop, hence my dillema

Comment: Your 2nd example is probably a different situation, and would be worth being separated into its own question. It is usually a sign of opportunity to improve decoupling, but since there not enough details about what it does, it is only speculation.

Comment: I am unsure what more information I could give this is the entire code in question, the method called setHistoricFilter is just a simple setter for a HistoricFilter object. Could you explain what you mean by decoupling?

Comment: For context, this code is currently nested in a relatively new project, so there's objectively not a lot to show appart from react 18 and mobx boilerplate

Comment: As there is no information about `readingsStore`, it is hard to say what could be improved. If your project is simple, then it should be easy to share a [mcve] that shows your exact situation.